# State doesn't change in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I made a promise function to get a JSON file from the official NBA API. In this function I'm trying to update a `usestate`, but I keep getting an empty array after setting the state. What am I overlooking?

```
const Games = () => {
    const [gameData, setGameData] = useState([]);
    const { readableDate } = useContext(NBAContext);

    const insertTime = readableDate.split('/');


        useEffect(() => {
            const jsonSrc = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/${insertTime[2]}${insertTime[1]}${insertTime[0]}/scoreboard.json`;

            const getScores = async () => {
                        const response = await fetch(jsonSrc);
                        return await response.json()
                };

            getScores().then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
                setGameData(result);
                console.log(gameData);
            });

        }, [readableDate])
```

Comment: is this line returning a set of data: `const data = await response.json()` ??

Comment: you're overcomplicating by wrapping it in `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { }`. Just do `return await response.json()` and in the `getScores().then((result) => { }` line call `setGameData`. it probably won't solve your issue but should make it easier to debug

Comment: @Alain Yes this returns an array

Comment: I agree with @TomOakley. The line `getScores().then((result) => {` should give you the expected result.

Comment: @TomOakley I changed it but it still gives me an empty array

Comment: what line gives you an empty array? state changes (either hooks or `this.setState` in class components) are asynchronous so using `console.log` straight after may mean that it hasn't completed yet

Comment: @TomOakley line "console.log(gameData)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: actual answer - setting state, whether with `this.setState` or the `useState` hook, is an asynchronous process. This means that calling `console.log(gameData)` right after `setGameData(results)` will result in the previous result (in this case, empty array). If you want to access `gameData` variable with results of the API call, use another `useEffect` hook with `gameData` as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(gameData)
}, [gameData])
```

initial answer, code improvement/advice: remove the line where you wrap the code inside `getScores` in a promise, and just return the result of `await response.json()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const jsonSrc = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/${insertTime[2]}${insertTime[1]}${insertTime[0]}/scoreboard.json`;

  const getScores = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(jsonSrc);
      return await response.json()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err
    }
  }

   getScores().then((result) => {
     console.log(result)
     setGameData(result.games);
   });
}, [readableDate])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like setState, the setting of useState is also asynchronous. That's why the console.log(gameData) prints the empty array. Since its still the previous array.

After the setting of the data, a new render will be called with the updated data and you can display it.